# Table in HTML with 2 columns; first column is 7 rows, second column is 1 row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table in HTML.  7 rows in the first column, only 1 in the second.  I can't figure it out.  I feel like I am missing something simple.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/dL76ycha/

Comment: Yup.  That's it.  Only thing I'm adding is that the second column is going to span all of the rows.  But that's it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply put a second `td` element in the first row, and change its `rowspan` to `7`

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td rowspan="7">b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `rowspan` attribute to stretch the second column over the rows of the first column, as shown below.

**Reference:** http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6.1

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>C 1</td>
    <td rowspan="7">C 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the rowspan attribute to have a cell span multiple rows.

Code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1</td>
                <td rowspan="7">Row 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 7</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```